# How to sum over the columns of the output of an excel file in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum all the columns of a matrix I got from an excel file, but the problem is python ignores the first column and only computes the sum for the 2nd & 3rd columns of the 3x3 matrix.

Here is the output of `print(data)`:

```
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", header = None)
print(data.sum(axis=0))
```

Here is what's inside `data`:

```
      0     1   2
0  NaN   17.0   5
1     3   NaN  19
2     7  17.0   7
```

So what should I do to sum all the three columns?

Comment: @ScottBoston The same as the one printed in the question. Sorry I don't know how to put it in here.

Comment: `data.sum(1)` to sum each row (horizontally) or `data.sum()` to sum each column (vertically).

Comment: Can you print the output of `print(data.head())`?

Comment: @ScottBoston `data.sum()` only gives me 34 and 31 which are the results for the 2nd and the 3rd columns ignoring the first column.

Comment: Ah check the dtypes of your dataframe columns data.info()  You may need to change he the dtype of data[0].

Comment: @AmiTavory The output of the print is as posted. Sorry, I will edit this part in the my question.

Comment: @ScottBoston A row of them (indicating data[0], I guess) gives this `0    3 non-null object` if that's what you mean

Comment: yes, column is not an numeric field therefore it is getting skipped by sum.  You'll need to astype to float then sum.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks a lot, Scott. It's done.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your columns are supposed to be floats, you can declare this while performing the import:

```
# where the range is the number of columns you have
dtypes = {col: float for col in range(3)}
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", header = None, dtype = dtypes)
print(data.sum())
```

[image: out]